# C++ TicTacToe errorClass problems

Tags: c++, boolean

I am trying to learn C++ and I have made litte tictactoe game but somethings wrong. I've tried to make a error bool. But somethings wrong with it. I've tried for 2 hours now and I can't find out how to solve the problem. Whats wrong? When I type in 2 2, which is should work, The error message pops up and it says invalid move. But the X or O will still pop up on the board
Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

const int rows = 3;
const int elements = 3;

char SetPlayer;
char SetEnemyPlayer;

char chooseTurn = 0;

char board[rows][elements];

void Clear()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < elements; j++)
        {
            board[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
}

void Show()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < elements; j++)
        {
            std::cout << " " << board[i][j] << " |";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "------------" << std::endl;
    }
}

void StartTurn()
{
    std::cout << "Which character would you like to be? (X or O) "; std::cin >> chooseTurn;
        switch (chooseTurn){
        case 'O':
            std::cout << "You have choosen O" << std::endl << std::endl;
            chooseTurn = 'O';
            break;    

        case 'X':
            std::cout << "You have choosen X" << std::endl << std::endl;
            chooseTurn = 'X';
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Enter a valid character" << std::endl;
            StartTurn();    

    }
}

bool PlayerAttack(int x, int y, char PlayerAttackChar)
{
    if (board[x][y] == ' ')
    {
        board[x][y] = PlayerAttackChar;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool EnemyAttack(int x, int y, char PlayerAttackChar)
{
    if (board[x][y] == ' ')
    {
        board[x][y] = PlayerAttackChar;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}    

bool OWinner()
{
    if (board[0][0] == 'O' && board[0][1] == 'O' && board[0][2] == 'O' ||
        board[0][0] == 'O' && board[1][0] == 'O' && board[2][0] == 'O' ||
        board[0][0] == 'O' && board[1][1] == 'O' && board[2][2] == 'O' ||
        board[0][1] == 'O' && board[1][1] == 'O' && board[2][1] == 'O' ||
        board[0][2] == 'O' && board[1][2] == 'O' && board[2][0] == 'O' ||
        board[0][2] == 'O' && board[1][2] == 'O' && board[2][2] == 'O' ||
        board[1][0] == 'O' && board[1][1] == 'O' && board[1][2] == 'O' ||
        board[2][0] == 'O' && board[2][1] == 'O' && board[2][2] == 'O')
    {
        std::cout << "You won!" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}    

bool XWinner()
{
        if (board[0][0] == 'X' && board[0][1] == 'X' && board[0][2] == 'X' ||
            board[0][0] == 'X' && board[1][0] == 'X' && board[2][0] == 'X' ||
            board[0][0] == 'X' && board[1][1] == 'X' && board[2][2] == 'X' ||
            board[0][1] == 'X' && board[1][1] == 'X' && board[2][1] == 'X' ||
            board[0][2] == 'X' && board[1][2] == 'X' && board[2][0] == 'X' ||
            board[0][2] == 'X' && board[1][2] == 'X' && board[2][2] == 'X' ||
            board[1][0] == 'X' && board[1][1] == 'X' && board[1][2] == 'X' ||
            board[2][0] == 'X' && board[2][1] == 'X' && board[2][2] == 'X')
        {
            std::cout << "You won!" << std::endl;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
}

bool error(int x, int y)
{
    if (board[x][y] != ' ')
    {
        return true;
    }
}    

int main()
{
    Clear();
    StartTurn();
    Show();
    if (chooseTurn == 'X')
    {
        SetPlayer = 'X';
        SetEnemyPlayer = 'O';
    }
    else
    {
        SetPlayer = 'O';
        SetEnemyPlayer = 'X';
    }
    int pos1 = 0;
    int pos2 = 0;
    bool Xwinner = false;
    bool Owinner = false;
    int PlayerTurn = 0;
    while (!Xwinner && !Owinner)
    {
        while (PlayerTurn == 0)
        {

            bool yourAttack = false;
            PlayerTurn++;
            std::cout << SetPlayer << " turn. Please input a coordinate: "; std::cin >> pos1 >> pos2; std::cout << std::endl;
            pos1 -= 1;
            pos2 -= 1;
            if (error(pos1, pos2))
            {
                std::cout << "Please enter a valid position (1 to 3)" << std::endl;
                PlayerTurn = 0;
            }
            PlayerAttack(pos1, pos2, SetPlayer);
            Show();

        }
        while (PlayerTurn != 0)
        {
            PlayerTurn = 0;
            std::cout<< SetEnemyPlayer << " turn. Please input a coordinate: "; std::cin >> pos1 >> pos2; std::cout << std::endl;
            pos1 -= 1;
            pos2 -= 1;
            if (error(pos1, pos2))
            {
                std::cout << "Please enter a valid position (1 to 3)" << std::endl;
                PlayerTurn = 1;
            }
            EnemyAttack(pos1, pos2, SetEnemyPlayer);
            Show();
            // AI
        }
        Xwinner = XWinner();
        Owinner = OWinner();
    }
}
```

Comment: "But something is wrong with it" Does not give enough information. You should give sample input and output. What you want it to do, and what it is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error function will not return anything if the move is valid, and cause undefined behavior. You want to add a return false; after the if statement. Also you want to make sure x and y are in the bounds of the array.

```
bool error(int x, int y)
{
    if(x > 2 || y > 2 || board[x][y] != ' ') 
    {
         return true;
    }

    return false;

}
```

Also, you probably want you if(error) checks to be in a loop. So the game won't continue until the player enters a valid move.

```
while (error(pos1, pos2))
{
    std::cout << "Please enter a valid position (1 to 3)" << std::endl;
    PlayerTurn = 0;
}
```

Comment: @user2589195 you got your answer is, more than fix itself this is useful to learn something else: 1) debug your code, always. step by step if you can't figure out what's wrong. 2) compiler warnings are your friends, don't ignore them.